# Search Two Dimensional Array for Match on both Dimensions - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am a new Swift developer.  I am using Swift 4.2 and XCode 10.1.

I'm sure this is not hard, but I have searched for two days and tried many different methods to determine whether a combination of `contactID` and `phoneNumber` exists in an array of `Favorites`, which is a struct model with those two variables.

```
struct Favorite {
    var favoriteNumber:String
    var contactID:String
}
```

I have a `contactID` and I have a `phoneNumber` and I need to search through the array of `Favorites` to see if there is a `Favorite` that has these exact two strings.  The array of `Favorites` is saved in `UserDefaults`.  Here's the initializer for that:

```
// Set an empty array of Favorites on the first save of the user.
    defaults.set([Favorite](), forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.storedFavorites)
```

I tried creating a `Favorite` with my numbers to check, and then running a `.contains` (where) on the array.  Like this:

```
// Make a Favorite with the contact ID and phone number passed in
    var checkContact = Favorite(favoriteNumber:phoneNumber.description, contactID:contact.contactDetails.identifier)
```

But I keep getting errors in Xcode that I can't resolve.  Here's my latest code that doesn't work (from the Apple Documentation).  This one gives an error about using `=` in a boolean context (which is straight from the Apple Documentation example), but even if I change it to `==` it gives another error that `==` cannot be applied to two Favorite operands.

```
let isAFavorite = user?.favorites!.contains { element in
        if checkContact = element {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
```

So I'm stuck.  What is the best way to check for a combination of the `contactID` and `favoriteNumber` in the array of `Favorites` using Swift 4?  Also, when I find a match, I need a reference to that `Favorite` in the array so I can remove it if the user `unFavorites` the number.

Comment: `let isAFavorite = user?.favorites!.contains(where { $0. favoriteNumber = phoneNumber.description && $0.contactId == contact.contactDetails.identifier})` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a filter for all matches

```
let isAFavorites = user?.favorites?.filter { $0 == checkContact } ?? []
```

or for the first hit

```
if let item = user?.favorites?.first(where:{ $0 == checkContact }) {
   ///
}
```

---

```
struct Favorite : Equatable {
    var favoriteNumber:String
    var contactID:String
}
```

Comment: `filter()` returns an array, no? Not a bool. So instead, `first(where:) != nil` might be better and would stop in the first found instead of checking the whole array.

Comment: @Larme it really depends on op need so will supply both options

Comment: I am seeing == cannot be applied to two Favorite operands still.

Comment: Just saw the Equatable... will try now.

Comment: You need to make it Equatable